# how can I create nav and tab style in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp

this page show many type of tab. But i want another style..

I want to mix style nav and tab.

I want to make main style below image.

[image]

How can i make this style?

thank you.

Comment: what do you mean? Do you want all the tab menu in the content of `Home` tab or you want exactly like its in the image you provided???

Comment: This image is sample.. If i click Home, Home menu show sub menu. Also if i click Menu 1, Menu 1 show Menu 1's sub menu,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bhavuksuthar/DTcHh/13678/)

I just make a little changes in `tab-content`
Let me know if that answers your question or any changes you were looking